# visual studio c++ external dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

In my visual studio project I had a file (say called f.h) which I did not require any more and may have incorrectly removed (by just pressing delete in the solution explorer of visual studio.

Now what I observe is that file is showing up in the "external dependencies" list and causing a compile error.

The compile error is caused as follows (f.h has a #include "x.h" which i do not need and hence removed).

So the question is how to figure out how "f.h" got there in the "external dependencies" and if I can remove it the compile error will go away.

Comment: Have you tried *Rebuilding* your project? If that doesn't work, close Visual Studio, delete all its temporary files and try rebuilding the project. Also, make sure no other file is including *f.h* of course.

Comment: Sometimes ___rebuilding___ is all that is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My educated guess is that you still have a file that includes the "f.h" file

Do a ctrl+shift+f and search for #include "f.h" and see if that exists anywhere in your solution.

Even when a header file is not included in the solution project it will still get compiled into the source if it is referenced somewhere.

Comment: perfect. that was solution. than you very much.